# Jquery Sortables - Sub Menus

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a challenge with CSS and Jquery Sortables.
I am extremely new to Jquery so I have no idea how to achieve this.

Here is the goal:

1. To have a horizontal plane of Parent Menus.
   Parent menus can be sorted by dragging them from right to left.
   Each Parent Menu Has its own unique ID.
2. Each parent menu can have 0 - unlimited sub menus.

   1. Sub menus show up in a vertical fashion.
   2. Sub menus can be sorted (up and down)
   3. sub menus can also be moved to a different parent menu.

I have tried to accomplish this with sortables and nested ULs.  I have tried connected lists and nothing works =(

can someone please help me with a simple sample of 3 parent menus each having 3 sub menus.
My goal is to be able to move the sub menus to one parent, and re arrange the parents in the horizontal panel.

After each change a text box within a form on the page gets a serialized list of all the menus.

Here is what i have so far. 
But no jquery code:

Thanks in advance

Frank

```
    <style type="text/css"> 
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size:12pt;
    padding:20px;
    width: 800px;
    margin:auto;
    border:solid 1px black;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 16pt;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 13pt;
}
ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:20px;
}
.menuholder {
    background-color:#000;
    width:100%;
    height:35px;
}
#AllMenus {
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
    border:none;
    font-size:10px;
}
#AllMenus li {
    float:left;
    min-width:100px;
    border:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
#AllMenus li div {
    height:33px;
    min-width:114px;
    margin:0px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.parentmenu_item {
    width:100px;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#FFF;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:9px;
    padding-right:6px;
    padding-left:6px;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    border-right:#242424 1px solid;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.placeHolder div {
    background-color: #0FF !important;
    border: dashed 1px gray !important;
    width:53px;
}
#babylist, #babylist2, #babylist3, #babylist4 {
    width:114px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0px;
    border:none;
    padding:0px;
    padding:none;
}
#babylist li, #babylist2 li, #babylist3 li, #babylist4 li {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#333;
    color:#CCC;
    text-align:left;
    padding:6px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h1>jQuery List DragSort Example</h1> 
<a href="http://dragsort.codeplex.com/">Homepage</a><br/> 
<br/> 
<h2>PARENT MENUS</h2> 
<form name="sortForm" method="get"> 
  <input name="ParentsortOrder" type="text" id="ParentsortOrder" size="100"> 
  <button type="submit" class="submit3" name="submit"><span>Save & Continue...</span></button> 
</form> 
<div style="clear:both;"></div> 
<br /> 
<br /> 
<div style="background-image:url(../Users/all/bkri/fs/phase_8.jpg); min-width:500px; height:500px; max-width:1920px;"> 
<div class="menuholder"> 
<!--For Background Menu Bar --> 
<!--Menus List --> 
<ul id="AllMenus"> 
        <!--Top Menu --> 
        <li id="P1"> 
          <div> <span class="parentmenu_item"> Menu 1 </span> 
            <!--Child Menus --> 
            <ul id="babylist"> 
              <li id="s1"><span id="spandex">My Pictures </span></li> 
              <li id="s2"><span id="spandex">My Music </span></li> 
              <li id="s3"><span>My Docs </span></li> 
              <li id="s4"><span>My Friends </span></li> 
              <li id="s5"><span>My Books </span></li> 
              <li id="s6"><span>My Computer </span></li> 
              <li id="s7"><span>My Network </span></li> 
              <li id="s8"><span>My Test </span></li> 
            </ul> 
          </div> 
        </li> 


        <!--Top Menu --> 
        <li id="P2"> 
          <div> <span class="parentmenu_item"> Menu 2 </span> 
            <!--Child Menus --> 
            <ul id="babylist2"> 
              <li id="s9"><span>Milk</span></li> 
              <li id="s10"><span>Cheese </span></li> 
              <li id="s11"><span>Eggs </span></li> 
              <li id="s12"><span>Bacon </span></li> 
              <li id="s13"><span>Flour </span></li> 
            </ul> 
          </div> 
        </li> 


        <!--Top Menu --> 
        <li id="P3"> 
          <div> <span class="parentmenu_item"> Menu 3 </span> 
            <!--Child Menus --> 
            <ul id="babylist3"> 
              <li id="s14"><span>Cow</span></li> 
              <li id="s15"><span>Pig </span></li> 
              <li id="s16"><span>Horse </span></li> 
              <li id="s17"><span>Lamb </span></li> 
            </ul> 
          </div> 
        </li> 


        <!--Top Menu --> 
        <li id="P4"> 
          <div> <span class="parentmenu_item"> Menu 4 </span> 
            <!--Child Menus --> 
            <ul id="babylist4"> 
              <li id="s19"><span>Bob</span></li> 
              <li id="s20"><span>Kevin </span></li> 
              <li id="s21"><span>Nancy </span></li> 
              <li id="s22"><span>Stacy </span></li> 
              <li id="s23"><span>Rochelle </span></li> 
            </ul> 
          </div> 
        </li> 
</ul>  
</div>  <!--End Top Menu Bkr --> 
</div>  <!--End Background -->
```

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED IT!
TOOK ALL DAY,

Now just gotta figure out how to serialize the list..
Hope this code sample helps someone out there.

The css Reset linked should not make a different in this.
CSS is very sloppy on my part but it gets the job done.
Works in IE and Chrome.

Here is how it looks:

[image: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/065de5a1ac.png]

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQueryUI Sortables</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Admin/resources/css/reset.css"/>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<style type="text/css">


body {
    background-color: #CCC;
    margin:25px;}



body,td,th {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}


.all-menu {list-style-type:none; margin:0px; padding:0px; width:100%;}
.p-menu {width:115px; margin:0px; padding:0px; float:left; list-style-type:none;  }
.p-menu-title {float:left; margin:0px; padding:0px; width:115px; background-color:#000; cursor:move; color:white; text-align:left;  font-size:10px; font-weight:bold; border-bottom:1px solid #111; border-left:1px solid #111; text-align:center; padding-bottom:15px; padding-top:15px;}
.ui-state-highlight {float:left; margin:0px; height: 20px; width:100%; background-color:#AFA; text-align:left; padding:0px;; margin:0px;  font-size:10px; border:2px green dashed;}
.ui-state-highlight-top {float:left; margin:0px; height: 40px; width:115px;; background-color:#aabeff; text-align:left; padding:0px;; margin:0px;  font-size:10px; border:2px blue dashed;}



.all-sub-menu {list-style-type:none; margin:0px; padding:0px; width:115px; min-height:250px; display:block;} 
.s-menu {width:115px; list-style-type:none; margin:0px; padding:0px; float:left;}
.s-menu-title {float:left; width:112px; background-color:#111; padding:10px; color:black; text-align:left; padding:0px; font-size:10px; border-bottom:1px solid #222; border-left:1px solid #222;padding-top:8px; padding-bottom:8px; color:#FFF; padding-left:3px; cursor:pointer;}
#drag-handle {cursor:move; margin:0px; padding:0px; width:500px;}


</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="serialStr" size="150" />Serialized Result
</form>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<br /><br />
<br />
<br />

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<ul id="sortable_parent" class="all-menu">

    <!--Parent Menu -->
    <li class="p-menu">
        <div class="p-menu-title"> 123456789112345</div><!--parent menu title and drag handle -->
        <ul id="sortable_child1" class="all-sub-menu">
            <li class="s-menu"><div class="s-menu-title"> Sub 1</div></li>  
            <li class="s-menu"><div class="s-menu-title"> Sub 2</div></li>
            <li class="s-menu"><div class="s-menu-title"> Sub 3</div></li>
            <li class="s-menu"><div class="s-menu-title"> Sub 4</div></li>
            <li ></li>  <!--Empty So things can be dropped -->  
        </ul>
    </li>


    <!--Parent Menu -->
    <li class="p-menu">
        <div class="p-menu-title"> MENU 2</div><!--parent menu title and drag handle -->
        <ul id="sortable_child2" class="all-sub-menu">
            <li class="s-menu"><div class="s-menu-title"> Sub 11</div></li>
            <li ></li>  <!--Empty So things can be dropped -->  

      </ul>
    </li>

    <!--Parent Menu -->
    <li class="p-menu">
        <div class="p-menu-title"> MENU 3</div><!--parent menu title and drag handle -->
        <ul id="sortable_child3" class="all-sub-menu">
            <li class="s-menu"><div class="s-menu-title"> Sub 21</div></li> 
            <li class="s-menu"><div class="s-menu-title"> Sub 22</div></li>
            <li class="s-menu"><div class="s-menu-title"> Sub 23</div></li>
            <li class="s-menu"><div class="s-menu-title"> Sub 24</div></li> 
            <li ></li>  <!--Empty So things can be dropped -->  

      </ul>
    </li>

    <!--Parent Menu -->
    <li class="p-menu">
        <div class="p-menu-title"> MENU 4</div><!--parent menu title and drag handle -->
        <ul id="sortable_child4" class="all-sub-menu">
            <li class="s-menu"><div class="s-menu-title"> Sub 31</div></li> 
            <li class="s-menu"><div class="s-menu-title"> Sub 32</div></li>
            <li class="s-menu"><div class="s-menu-title"> Sub 33</div></li>
            <li class="s-menu"><div class="s-menu-title"> Sub 34</div></li>
            <li class="s-menu"><div class="s-menu-title"> Sub 35</div></li>
            <li ></li>  <!--Empty So things can be dropped -->  

      </ul>
    </li>


</ul>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>



<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        //  Make parent top menus sortable..
            $('#sortable_parent').sortable({ handle: '.p-menu-title', cursor: 'hand', placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight-top'  });
        //  $("#sortable_parent").disableSelection();
        });
    </script>




<script type="text/javascript">
    //Try to connect all sub menus so user can sort them or drag them to a different top menu..
    $(function() {
        $(".all-sub-menu").sortable({
            connectWith: '.all-sub-menu', placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight', dropOnEmpty: false
        }).disableSelection();
    });
    </script>
















</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i like your solution alot.  I may use your code to make up something for a project im currently doing.  To make it easier to see Ive placed your above code in a JSFiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/ZDZ5x/

My challenge is trying to create a vertical menu aswell as this horizontal version.

Comment: @SubstanceD, Thanks for jsFiddle.  Were you able to ever get the menus to work on the side like you wanted?